# Accessing value of SELECT in Internet Explorer 6

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I am looking for simple and short solution of accessing SELECT value on HTML website in Internet Explorers (6 and 7).

HTML

```
<select id="s1">
    <option>Option1</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("s1").options[document.getElementById("s1").selectedIndex].value
```

Above code do not work. I get empty strings.

I found [one solution](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1017132) - I would have to make every option look like this:

```
<option value="Option1">Option1</option>
```

That works but my website mostly cosist of forms, so such operation increase its size by 50-70%.

Do you know any other ways ?

PS. I've read that I should use "text" instead of "value", but I am not sure about that. I couldn't find what are the consequences of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use,

```
document.getElementById("s1").options[document.getElementById("s1").selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

Comment: Is it better than using ".text" ? What is the diffrence?

Comment: It shouldn't make much difference, unless the contents of the option tag contains HTML, in which case innerHTML will pick up the entire contents (HTML and all).

Comment: +1.  You're right `.innerHTML` is the only thing that works in IE6.  I deleted my answer.

Comment: Only text is valid inside an `<option>` element. `text` is the correct property.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you don't have a `value` attribute in your option:

```
<select id="s1">
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
</select>
```

This would give you the correct value back.

Newer browsers send the `option text` instead of the missing value attribute.

As for your question as to what to use, the proper semantic way would be to use `value` attribute. What if your display text is different than value? Would you change your design again?

If page size is a concern, try removing [whitespace](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/whitespace/) or [gzipping content](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) instead of breaking the semantics. Note that some older IE6 versions (IE6 with SP3 is fine I guess) may not play well with GZipped content.